# arrow color of vectorplot3d

Tags: plotting

I would like to create a vortex field. I have a problem with the color, I expect to obtain a uniform color, but depending on the view (i.e tilting the geometry) I observe the different color, How I can avoid that?

```
ro = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
theta = ArcTan[x, y];

With[{R = 200}, VectorPlot3D[{-Sin[theta], Cos[theta], 0}, {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}, {z, 0, 0.001}, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 800, Axes -> False, VectorColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][(#6 + 1)/2] &), VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorPoints -> {20, 20, 2}, VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorScale -> {Small, Automatic, #3 &}, BoxRatios -> {5, 5, 0.15}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]]
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Use `"Neutral"`  in `Lighting` i.e add option `Lighting -> "Neutral"` to the `VectorPlot3D`.

Comment: When I add that line, the arrows at the bottom are bright and the arrows at the top are shaded.